# An unusual symmetric inequality of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Given $\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta+\sin^2\gamma=2 $.
I have to prove that $ \left| \begin{matrix} \cos\alpha & \cos\beta & \sin\gamma\\\sin\alpha & \cos\beta & \cos\gamma\\\cos\alpha & \sin\beta & \cos\gamma  \end{matrix} \right| \leq 2\sqrt2 \sin\alpha \sin\beta \sin\gamma $.
I decided to directly expand the determinant, the left becomes $ |2\cos \alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma-\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)| $.
This is quite different from what I encountered before as the equal sign doesn't happen when $\alpha=\beta=\gamma $ like the usual symmetric inequalities.
edit: sorry i forgot the condition that $ 0\leq\alpha, \beta,  \gamma \leq \pi $

Comment: $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ , are the angles made by a line with x , y and z axis respectively, then the summation of squares of their sin is 2, and in that case $\alpha$+ $\beta$+ $\gamma$ = 4pi

Comment: +1, and I wonder why I'm the only person who's voted in this question's favor when it's got an answer with two up-votes?

Comment: A good answer does not necessary implies it belongs to a equally good question.

Comment: @ 5ToM sorry my bad i forgot the condition :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that these sines are non-negative (otherwise absolute value bars are missing in the RHS).  Consider the rows of the matrix as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Then the lengths of those vectors are $\sqrt{2} \sin(\gamma)$, $\sqrt{2} \sin(\alpha)$ and $\sqrt{2} \sin(\beta)$ respectively.  The maximum volume of a parallelepiped with those edge lengths is the product of these lengths (if the rows are orthogonal).

Comment: i see, a great deal of complication has been avoided by observing a simple property of determinant.

Comment: mathematical elegancy!