# Prove an inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a vector and let $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ be the angles
between $v$ and coordinate axes, where $0 \leq \alpha, \beta, \gamma \leq\pi$.

Prove that

$$ \mathrm{abs}\left(\;\left|
\begin{matrix} 
  \cos\alpha & \cos\beta & \sin\gamma\\ 
  \sin\alpha & \cos\beta & \cos\gamma\\ 
  \cos\alpha & \sin\beta & \cos\gamma
\end{matrix} \right|\;\right) \leq 2\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma$$
where $\mathrm{abs}(a) = |a|$ is the absolute value of $a$.

My opinion is to consider 2 cases, since there is at most one of the three angles whose sine is $0$.

(1)If there is one angle whose sine is $0$, then it's trivial that LHS=RHS=$0$.

(2)If no such angle, then just divide $\sin\alpha$,$\sin\beta$, and $\sin\gamma$ on both sides, the the problem is reduced to

$$ \mathrm{abs}\left(\left|
\begin{matrix} 
  \cot\alpha & \cot\beta & 1\\ 
  1 & \cot\beta & \cot\gamma\\ 
  \cot\alpha & 1 & \cot\gamma 
\end{matrix} \right|\right) \leq 2\sqrt{2}.$$

Then the LHS is just the volume of the parallelpiped formed by the three column vectors.

But I don't know how to do next? Any suggestion? Thanks very much!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119362/an-unusual-symmetric-inequality-of-trigonometric-functions) for one approach.

Comment: yes, thanks.it's much easier than what i thought.